# Ubuntu MATE Battery percentage shows up in lightdm but not available after logging in

Tags: 22.04, battery, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu MATE 22.04 in a laptop.

While the battery percentage shows up in the login screen (lightdm), after logging in, it only shows the estimated time remaining.
[image]

<sup>Login Screen</sup>

[image]

<sup>After logging in</sup>

How to change this behavior so that I can see the remaining battery percentage while I am logged in?

Comment: When I click the battery icon I get a menu like this https://imgur.com/Lv94XkO but I think I use the indicator-app-complete applet

Comment: @OrganicMarble Are you also on 22.04?

Comment: No, I missed that. This is a 20.04 install, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the workaround in [Ubuntu MATE Community Discourse](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-22-04-not-showing-battery-percentage/25415/3?u=apandada1).

---

Open **Control Center**, head over to **Indicators > Power** and enable **Show percentage** on the panel.